# how to add screens to preview mode in Xcode 8?

Tags: xcode

How I can get more screens with preview mode?

There are all devices that I can added as preview

[image]

but I also need iPhone 5, 6, 6s

Comment: I think iPhone SE is same as iPhone 5. And iPhone 7 is the same as 6/6S. I could be wrong about this though.